# Unable to debug/start/stop xsl in visual studio 2015RC community

Tags: xml, visual-studio, debugging, xslt, visual-studio-2015

Hope someone can help,

The options to either debug/start/stop an xsl file are greyed out in the xml editor toolbar- I was following this approach [Walkthrough: Debug an XSLT Style Sheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms255602(v=vs.110).aspx). To test this simply open or create and xsl file and enable the xml toolbar. From here the relevant start and debug buttons should be enabled. Additionally the xml menu only contains Create Schema (greyed out) and Schemas...

This all works fine in vs2013 community.

Is this a known issue in vs2015RC? If not any ideas howto remedy?

Edit: Just reinstalled VS and the problem is still there so maybe this functionality is not working in the RC - would appreciate if anyone else could feedback.

Thank you

Comment: Same issue here with VS2015 RTM Community

Answer (score 2):

Asked this on the respective Microsoft forums and the issue was confirmed by another member there. Raised as a bug on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1438310/unable-to-debug-xsl-in-visual-studio-2015rc-community)